# json result using python code

Tags: python, json

I need to do some proper set of key value pairing of json result,
    below is the current json format:

```
test = [{"banana":
 [{"colour":"oput","fruit":"banana","price":"price=$0.05976"}], "mango" :
  [{"colour": "XYZ", "fruit":"mango","price": "price=$0.26538"}], 
  "greps": [{"colour": "AIR", "fruit": "greps", "price": "price=$0.02334"}], 
   "apple": [{"colour": "yellow", "fruit": "apple", "price": 
   "price=$0.39562"}, 
        {"colour": "darkred", "fruit": "apple", "price": "price=$11.6107"}, 
        {"colour": "red", "fruit": "apple", "price": "price=$2.19313"}]
  }]
```

I  need to achieve the below format result:

```
    result = [{"fruitName":"banana","priceList":[{"colour": "oput","fruit": 
          "banana","price":"price=$0.05976"}]},
          {"fruitName":"apple","priceList": [{"colour":"yellow","fruit": 
          "apple","price":"price=$0.39562"},
                                  {"colour": "darkred","fruit": 
          "apple","price": "price=$11.6107"},   
                                  {"colour": "red","fruit":"apple","price": 
          "price=$2.19313"}]
           }]
```

Comment: do you mind telling WHAT do you want to do with this json?

Comment: SO is NOT a write my code service. Share what you've tried so far please.

Comment: Ok, so what is your question? You need to show us the Python code you have written so far, clearly explaining where you are stuck. If your code curently produces some output or error message then you need to include that in your question.

Comment: test = [ ] is list type, 
also want results with same result [ ] list data type.

Comment: lines=['311,0.30239,mango,pink,\r\n', '12,0.16763,mango,yello,\r\n', '513,0.20925,mango,green,\r\n', '149,0.09466,apple,red,\r\n', '315,0.01538,mango,pink,\r\n',"65,0.12,banana,yellow,\r\n','149,0.09440,apple,black,\r\n']
      tempalldata = []
   for l in lines:
    l=l.split(",")
    Prices[l[0]]=l[1].rstrip('0')
    Fruits[l[0]]=l[2].rstrip('0')
    Colours[l[0]]=l[3].rstrip('0')
    array = {}
    array['callRate']='Rate=$'+Prices[l[0]]
    array['countryCode']=Fruits[l[0]]
    array['ISP']=Colours[l[0]]
    prmangot array
    tempalldata.append(array)

Comment: we need below json format result from above commented code:
{"fruitName":"mango","priceList":[{"colour": "pink","fruit":"mango","price":"price=$0.30239"},
{"colour": "yello","fruit":"mango","price":"price=$0.16763"},
{"colour": "green","fruit":"mango","price":"price=$0.20925"},
{"colour": "pink","fruit":"mango","price":"price=$0.01538"}]},
{"fruitName":"apple","priceList": {"colour":"red","fruit":"apple","price":"price=$09466"},
{"colour": "black","fruit":"apple","price": "price=$0.09440"}]},
{"fruitName":"banana","priceList":{"colour":"yellow","fruit":"banana","price":"price=$0.12"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result=[]
for i in test[0]:
    temp = test[i]
    d={}
    d["fruitName"]=temp['fruit']
    d["priceList"]=[{"colour":temp["colour"],"price":temp["price"],"fruit":temp["fruit"]}]
    result.append(d)
```

Comment: test is not variable,

test = [ ] list type,
then also same method ?